# Effectiveness of Collections.shuffle

Tags: java, collections, random

I'm trying to create a lottery simulator in java and I'm beginning to become concerned about whether my generated numbers are random enough.

For example, my code for generating white ball numbers that are non repeating looks like this.

```
public static int[] genWhiteNums()
{
    int[] whitePicks = new int[5];
    Collections.shuffle(whiteDrawNums); //whiteDrawNums is an arraylist of numbers 1-59

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        whitePicks[i] = whiteDrawNums.get(i);
    }
    whiteDrawNums = createWhiteNums(); //Reordering

    return whitePicks;
}
```

Is picking the first 5 values from Collections.shuffle random enough?

Comment: What's random enough for your purposes? You need to define that.

Comment: random.org has an api you can use, its free for smaller amounts of random data.

Comment: I agree with Thegrinner, you definitely need to define what "random enough" means in this case.  Do you want it to be random in choosing distinct numbers from `whiteDrawNums`, or random in terms of how it picks numbers from that list, or do you mean that each time you call `getWhiteNums()`, you get a set that is always different from previously generated sets? These three questions have completely different (but complementary) answers.

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer. It lets you pick sufficiently distributed values from your already shuffled collection now.

Answer (score 3):

According to the doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

> Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of
>   randomness. All permutations occur with approximately equal
>   likelihood.
>
> The hedge "approximately" is used in the foregoing description because
>   default source of randomenss is only approximately an unbiased source
>   of independently chosen bits. If it were a perfect source of randomly
>   chosen bits, then the algorithm would choose permutations with perfect
>   uniformity.

It uses a linear time shuffling algorithm. I think it is random enough to meet most people's need.

Answer (score 2):

Collections.shuffle does a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle). Its in your considerations if it´s random enough

Answer (score 0):

Use `Random#nextInt()` to pick sufficiently distributed random values from your shuffled collection.

```
public static int[] genWhiteNums() {
    Random random = new Random();

    int[] whitePicks = new int[5];
    Collections.shuffle(whiteDrawNums);  // Arraylist 1-59

    for (int i = 0; i < whitePicks.length; i++) {
        whitePicks[i] = whiteDrawNums.get(
                        random.nextInt(i != 4 ? 12 : 11) + 12 * i);
    }

    whiteDrawNums = createWhiteNums(); // Reordering
    return whitePicks;
}
```

It's splitting the available indexes (0-58) into 4 groups of 12 and the last group of 11 and picking one random index every iteration of the loop. This should suffice your need for randomness adequately.